# Combine 2 MySQL queries into 1 query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine these two queries into a single query but I'm not having much luck and I'm starting to think that it's not possible.

The value returned in transfer_dtl from the first query is passed into the second query FROM. This value is an actual table name that is stored in the first query. This is currently done with php and loops through, but I wanted to eliminate that step if possible.

```
SELECT id, client, loc, transfer_dtl, update_processed FROM tbl_master WHERE downtime_update='Y'
```

```
transfer_dtl
-------------
load_dtl_1
load_dtl_5
load_dtl_7
load_dtl_9
```

```
SELECT added_datetime FROM $transfer_dtl WHERE client='1' AND loc='2' AND scale='3' AND type='D' ORDER BY added_datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

```
pseudo code...
if($added_datetime > $update_processed) 
then add to a list of scales to update
```

Basically by combining these two queries together what I need is a distinct list of any scale that is marked to update.

Comment: please share the sample data and expected output for both tables

Comment: `Table` name must be present in the query. The only way you can do this is with `dynamic query`.

Comment: The heart of your question is the subquery: `SELECT added_datetime FROM (SELECT id, client...)`. the pseudo code could also be in query-space but I'm too fuzzy on what is desired to take a crack at it.